# Why VideoView in android is taking too much time to load and play the video from http link?

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

Below is my Code :

```
  package com.example.videoplayer;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.app.ProgressDialog;
  import android.media.MediaPlayer;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.widget.MediaController;
  import android.widget.VideoView;

public class VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity {
    String TAG = "com.example.VideoPlayer";
    ProgressDialog progDailog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);

        final VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        videoView.setVideoPath("http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/android_book/movie.mp4");

        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new 
                MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()  {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                progDailog.dismiss();
                Log.i(TAG, "Duration = " + videoView.getDuration());
            }
        });

        videoView.start();
        progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait ...", "Retrieving data ...", `enter code here`true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.video_player, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try to play video with different url?

Comment: yes... same problem for all the videos

Comment: Check my answer below, it works fine for me.Let me know if you find any issues.

Comment: @Praksha long time has passed since you posted this question. What are you words of wisdom for others who encounter similar problem, like me? :)

Comment: @Sufian What are your words of wisdom for me.. as i am facing same problem. :P

Comment: @Kriti this is unfixable without diving deep into the Android framework code. I believe there's some sort of handshake which is creating the delay.

Comment: have you found out any solutions @Sufian . As i am struggling from almost a week

Comment: @saikrupa no I couldn't find a solution to it. I guess the only solution is to use a some video library like Vitamio, ijkplayer, ExoPlayer, etc. I assume they are free from this bug.

Comment: even i tried with exoplayer it is also slow like a videoview

Answer (score 0):

Check out this :

[Play http videos in VideoView](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-video-streaming-videoview-tutorial/)

This is my code :

```
public static void getVideoFromHttp(String urlPath) {

try {
// Start the MediaController
MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(mContext);
mediacontroller.setAnchorView(mVideoview);
// Get the URL from String VideoURL
Uri mVideo = Uri.parse(urlPath);
mVideoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
mVideoview.setVideoURI(mVideo);

} catch (Exception e) {
Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
e.printStackTrace();

}

mVideoview.requestFocus();
mVideoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
// Close the progress bar and play the video
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mVideoview.start();

}
});

mVideoview.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

}
});

}
```

Thanks

Comment: What problem are you facing? Did you check the example. It works fine for me.

Comment: Then it must be your internet's connectivity issue.

Comment: no video is playing fine in browser through the same wifi

Comment: Restart your device and give it a try.

Comment: @Praksha did you find any solution? cuz even i am facing same issue. Please let me know if you have found a solution....

Comment: I don't think this is a connectivity issue. Video player is working faster on iOS and Windows, but Android is taking longer. :|

Comment: @Mark13426, checkout my answer and update if that works.

Answer (score -1):

Don't do everything in the UI thread because it takes a lot of time. Do everything in `AsyncTask` and things will work out fine.

For beginners, [this link](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Working-with-MediaController,--VideoView-in-Android) describes how could you do it in `AsyncTask`.

Define a class which extends the `AsyncTask`:

```
public class BackgroundAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Uri, Void> {
    Integer track = 0;
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(PlayVideo.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, Please Wait...");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(final Uri... uri) {

        try {

            media=new MediaController(PlayVideo.this);
            video.setMediaController(media);
            media.setPrevNextListeners(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // next button clicked

                }
            }, new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    finish();
                }
            });
            media.show(10000);

            video.setVideoURI(uri[0]);
            video.requestFocus();
            video.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                    video.start();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });


        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(params[0]);

            publishProgress(uri);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Then, in the `onCreate()` method, just call the `execute()` method of this `BackgroundAsynchTask`:

```
video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
new BackgroundAsyncTask().execute("link-to-the-video");
```

Comment: Nonsense, you are doing nothing on background. `onProgressUpdate` is executed on the UI thread.